# How can i get path of my current debugging process via Windbg API?

Tags: c++, winapi, windbg

I have the following code:

```
#include "EPBreaker.hpp"

#include <DbgEng.h>
#include <wdbgexts.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

#define EXTENSION_VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define EXTENSION_VERSION_MINOR 0

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT CALLBACK EPBreaker(IDebugClient4* Client, PCSTR Args)
{
    IDebugControl* ptrIDebugControl = 0;
    IDebugSymbols4* ptrIDebugSymbols = 0;
    
    if (Client->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugControl), (PVOID*)&ptrIDebugControl)
        != S_OK) {
        ptrIDebugControl->Output(DEBUG_OUTCTL_ALL_CLIENTS, "ERROR ON IDebugControl QueryInterface");
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    if (Client->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugSymbols4), (PVOID*)&ptrIDebugSymbols)
        != S_OK) {
        ptrIDebugControl->Output(DEBUG_OUTCTL_ALL_CLIENTS, "ERROR ON IDebugSymbols QueryInterface\n");
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    std::string ModuleName; ModuleName.resize(MAX_PATH);
    ptrIDebugSymbols->GetModuleNameString(DEBUG_MODNAME_MODULE, 0, DEBUG_ANY_ID, ModuleName.data(), ModuleName.size(), NULL);

    ptrIDebugControl->Output(DEBUG_OUTCTL_ALL_CLIENTS, "Name: %s\n", ModuleName.c_str());
    return S_OK;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT CALLBACK DebugExtensionInitialize(PULONG Version, PULONG Flag)
{
    *Version = DEBUG_EXTENSION_VERSION(EXTENSION_VERSION_MAJOR, EXTENSION_VERSION_MINOR);
    *Flag = 0;
    return S_OK;
}
```

What method/API can I call to get the path to my current process in windbg?

How can i get this path, but via WinDbg API?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yb03.png)

Comment: `IDebugClient4* Client` have `SetEventCallbacksWide` method. you implement `IDebugEventCallbacksWide` and got `LoadModule` calls. also if you want only exe path - `K32GetProcessImageFileNameW` or `QueryFullProcessImageNameW`

Comment: On the top of my head I would have say `IDebugEventCallbacks::CreateProcess` but @RbMm method works too.

Comment: @Neitsa - really you correct - for exactly exe we get path from `CreateProcess`. `LoadModule` called for another dlls inside process, but not for exe. my mistake in first comment

Comment: @Neitsa hmm. I have a lot of problems with this approach.


Since I am a newbie in windbg, I do not know how to load extensions at the start, i.e. I cannot use "Command" at the very start (https://ibb.co/p4hZVZR ) In order for me to write commands, I need to open at least some exe(https://ibb.co/tLwY75j).

Comment: @Neitsa Also here is my code on CreateProcess and Attach, I seem to be doing everything right and I had about the same approach working, but without WinDbg(https://pastebin.com/zKukY1kQ ). When trying to attach some exe in this way, I get error(Cannot debug pid 25424, HRESULT 0x8000FFFF
"Catastrophic failure"), I tried to look for this problem during these two hours, but I didn't find anything =( I will be glad if you can help(https://ibb.co/CwdMwVM)

Comment: @Neitsa  The problem here is clearly not in the arguments, since the arguments I have are passed "D:\\Programs\\Games\\Kerbal Space Program 2\\KSP2_x64.exe
", also the process itself is being created successfully, but for some reason I can't join to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

```
std::string ModuleName;
ModuleName.resize(MAX_PATH);
ptrIDebugSymbols->GetModuleNameString(DEBUG_MODNAME_SYMBOL_FILE, 0, DEBUG_ANY_ID, ModuleName.data(), ModuleName.size(), NULL);
```